# Icons size and placement based on screensize

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a floating nav bar which would have approximately 10 button. On some screens they fit in all well on some they go out. I am trying to figure out if their is a way to do is other than media queries.

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  text-align: center;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

h3{
  color: #555;
}

#presentation{
  width: 480px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #FFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23); 
  transition: all 0.3s; 
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#presentation:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  transform: translateZ(10px);
}

#floating-button{
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #db4437;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #666;
}

.plus{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 55px;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  animation: plus-out 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#container-floating{
  position: fixed;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 50px;
}

#container-floating:hover{
  height: 400px;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#container-floating:hover .plus{
  animation: plus-in 0.15s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.edit{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 65px;
  transform: rotateZ(-70deg);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  animation: edit-out 0.3s;
}

#container-floating:hover .edit{
  animation: edit-in 0.2s;
   animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes edit-in{
    from {opacity: 0; transform: rotateZ(-70deg);}
    to {opacity: 1; transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
}

@keyframes edit-out{
    from {opacity: 1; transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to {opacity: 0; transform: rotateZ(-70deg);}
}

@keyframes plus-in{
    from {opacity: 1; transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to {opacity: 0; transform: rotateZ(180deg);}
}

@keyframes plus-out{
    from {opacity: 0; transform: rotateZ(180deg);}
    to {opacity: 1; transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
}

.nds{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  transform:  scale(0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nd1{
  background: #d3a411;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 120px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation: bounce-out-nds 0.3s linear;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;
}

.nd3{
  background: #3c80f6;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 180px;
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
    animation: bounce-out-nds 0.15s linear;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;
}

.nd4{
  background: #ba68c8;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 240px;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation: bounce-out-nds 0.1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;
}

.nd5{
  background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-X-aQXHatDQY/Uy86XLOyEdI/AAAAAAAAAF0/TBEZvkCnLVE/w140-h140-p/fb3a11ae-1fb4-4c31-b2b9-bf0cfa835c27');
  background-size: 100%;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 300px;
  animation-delay: 0.08s;
  animation: bounce-out-nds 0.1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;
}

@keyframes bounce-nds{
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
}

@keyframes bounce-out-nds{
    from {opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    to {opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
}

#container-floating:hover .nds{
  
  animation: bounce-nds 0.1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;
}

#container-floating:hover .nd3{
  animation-delay: 0.08s;
}
#container-floating:hover .nd4{
  animation-delay: 0.15s;
}
#container-floating:hover .nd5{
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.letter{
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.reminder{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.profile{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-floating">

  
  <div class="nd4 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="contract@gmail.com"><img class="reminder">
    <p class="letter">C</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nd3 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Reminder"><img class="reminder" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/bt/C3341AA7A1A076756462EE2E5CD71C11/1x/ic_reminders_speeddial_white_24dp.png" /></div>
  <div class="nd1 nds" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Edoardo@live.it"><img class="reminder">
    <p class="letter">E</p>
  </div>

  <div id="floating-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-original-title="Create" onclick="newmail()">
    <p class="plus">+</p>
    <img class="edit" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/bt/C3341AA7A1A076756462EE2E5CD71C11/1x/bt_compose2_1x.png">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'd say "other way around" is `javascript` but media query is a lot more handy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media screen` for more information 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp